# Error 3034 : The Vendor or VendorName value is required in SagePay test enviornment

Tags: opayo

We are getting Error 3034 : The Vendor or VendorName value is required in SagePay test environment

We have checked that vendor name is correct

Live SagePay link is working for SagePay

Can you please let us know proposed solution to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure this is resolved by now (hopefully), but to get decent answers for these questions, an example of what you are posting over to Sage Pay and the integration method you are using would help.

Comment: This is a bit old but, I was wondering what the problem was. I'm facing the same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Sage Pay Direct test, and it turned out to be the `Content-Type` not being set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The documentation states that the body of the registration transaction must be URL encoded, but does not mention the `Content-Type` header. This is kind of obvious if you understand how these HTTP messages are going to be parsed, but can result in this very misleading error message from the gateway if not correctly set.

So basically, if you get error number 3034, and you *do* have the `vendor` field set correctly, then the problem is likely that the remote Sage Pay gateway cannot parse the body of the transaction in the HTTP message you have POSTed. In that case you need to look at the complete message being sent.